# Validación de un checkbox

Tags: javascript

Al comprobar el código no me lleva a una página llamada "verifica.html" ni tampoco me muestra el alert, tengo dudas si en el ciclo if es posible que lo haya implementado mal.

Este es mi código:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var envia = document.getElementById("continuar").value;
    envia.onclick = function() {
        tarjeta = document.getElementById("tarjeta1").checked;
        tarjeta2 = document.getElementById("tarjeta2").checked;
        tarjeta3 = document.getElementById("tarjeta3").checked;
        paYpal = document.getElementById("paypal").checked;
        if ((tarjeta || tarjeta2 || tarjeta3 || paypal)) {
            return true;
            window.location.href = "verifica.html"
        } else {
            alert("Selecciona el método de pago efectivo para avanzar");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

index.html (nose como se llama tu html yo le puse index)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="input">
<label for="tarjeta1">Tarjeta 1</label><input type="checkbox" id="tarjeta1">
<label for="tarjeta2">Tarjeta 2</label><input type="checkbox" id="tarjeta2">
<label for="tarjeta3">Tarjeta 3</label><input type="checkbox" id="tarjeta3">
<label for="paypal">PayPal</label><input type="checkbox" id="paypal">
<input type="submit" class="stackoverflow" id="continuar">
</div>

<script src="jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var envia = document.getElementById("continuar");
console.log(envia)
envia.onclick = function() {
    tarjeta = document.getElementById("tarjeta1").checked;
    tarjeta2 = document.getElementById("tarjeta2").checked;
    tarjeta3 = document.getElementById("tarjeta3").checked;
    paypal = document.getElementById("paypal").checked;
    if ((tarjeta || tarjeta2 || tarjeta3  || paypal == true)) {
        window.location.href = "verifica.html"
    } else {
        alert("Selecciona el método de pago efectivo para avanzar");
    }
    }
  }
  </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Como te daras cuanta le quite el ".value" a :

```
var envia = document.getElementById("continuar").value;
```

y tambien el "return true" a:

```
if ((tarjeta || tarjeta2 || tarjeta3 || paypal)) {
        return true;
        window.location.href = "verifica.html"
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes dos problemas:

- Obtienes el valor del elemento `#continuar` y le asocias una acción en el evento click, cuando la propiedad `value` obtiene el valor de un tipo de elemento (inputs, selects, etc.). La forma correcta debería ser:

  ```
  let btnContinue = document.getElementById('continuar');
  btnContinue.onClick = (e) => { ... }
  ```
- Utilizas `return` antes de realizar la acción deseada si se cumple la condición. La palabra `return` lo que hace es retornar un valor o simplemente terminar la función en el momento en que se declara. Si llamas a `return` antes de realizar la acción deseada, simplemente esta nunca se ejecutará. Lo correcto debería ser:

  ```
  if(card1 || card2 || card3 || paypal) {
      return window.location = 'verifica.html';
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas colocando el `return`, antes del `window.location`, al ejecutar un `return` la función termina justo en ese punto.

Debería ser:

```
if(( tarjeta || tarjeta2 || tarjeta3 || paypal)){
  window.location.href = "verifica.html";
  return true;
}
```

También asegúrate de culminar cada sentencia con ;

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, acabo de realizar el cambio en el código sin embargo sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Estas usando :  var envia = document.getElementById("continuar").value;
    usa var envia = document.getElementById("continuar");